# How to solve this type of equations automatically?

Tags: math, equation, boolean-logic

i.e.

```
x = z + (x^y)v(x^z)
y = z + (x^z)
z = (x^y)
```

Think that x, y, z are all 8-bits number in these equations, which means the add operation would occur carry in.

Is there some program or algorithm that can solve these equations programmatically ?

Advances, what if bring shift opration into equations ? Suppose change the second equation to

```
y = z + (x^z)<<<5
```

more serious,

```
y = z + (x^z)<<<x
```

Is it possible to solve it programmatically ? If not, how to solve it by hands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Boolean satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem). Basically any set of boolean equations can be reduced to a single normal form expression (a V b V ... V c) ^ (x V y V ... V z). the BSAT problem asks if there are a set of boolean values which mean the expression evaluates to true. In computational terms this is an NP-complete problem, basically it will take a lot computing power to solve for expressions involving lots of variables. There are programs lower down the page which can solve this problem for large set of values.

If the number of variable you have is small the simplest will be a brute-force algorithm. Try every possibility. If you have n variables then there will be 2^n sets of values to try. If n=10 thats only 1024 sets to test which would be done in the blink of an eye.

Without the + or shift operators you could treat the equations bitwise, say `x=(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8)` giving one set of equations for each set of bits, which could be solve independently. Adding + and shift make things a bit more complex but they are still a set of bitwise equations. For only three variables brute-force is still reasonable with 2^24 =16,777,216 sets to try this could be solved in a second on modern hardware. Four variables would take 256 times as long and five variables starts getting slow.